# High resolution timing API for multiple threads

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, timing

I am attempting to implement a multi-threaded 3D application where one thread performs constant rate scene updates (at 120Hz), and another performs rendering (potentially with very short frame times, e.g. at 400Hz), with shared data triple buffered. According to the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ee417693%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on timing `QueryPerformanceCounter` performs poorly with use by multiple threads:

> Computation of timing on multiple threads — for example, with each thread associated with a specific processor — greatly reduces performance of multi-core systems.

However high precision timing is required on the update thread in order to ensure updates occur at the correct interval, and on the rendering thread in order to get accurate frame times for interpolation, so what is the common way of solving this?

**UPDATE:**

I have now created a small test program to test this "great reduction" in performance. It times a run of calling `QueryPerformanceCounter` 100000000 times. It does this for one thread, then runs it for two threads in parallel on separate cores. As per the advice of the article each thread has its affinity set to a distinct core. The results of the test on my machine are surprising if you go by the word of the article.

Results:

*Note: These results include time spent incrementing the loop counter (a 64-bit int) and jumping to the start of the loop, so actual execution times are shorter.*

> ```
> 1 Thread:
>
>    Execution in 3255313449 ns
>
>    Approximately 32.6 ns per call
>
> 2 Threads:
>
> Thread 1:
>
>    Execution in 3278105881 ns
>
>    Approximately 32.8 ns per call
>
> Thread 2:
>
>    Execution in 3271422015 ns
>
>    Approximately 32.7 ns per call
> ```

This shows no significant performance impact at all from using two threads to call `QueryPerformanceCounter`. Is this anomalous behaviour, or is the article incorrect for the majority of modern machines?

Comment: Would it not make more sense to simply synchronise the rendering thread to the updates of the buffers in the scene update thread?

Comment: In general, if you RELY on windows producing precise timing, it will probably go wrong every so often, since Windows isn't exactly a high performance REAL TIME os.

Comment: Why do you need a 400Hz refresh rate, when screens can't even reach half of that?

Comment: The article states: `This article suggests a more accurate, reliable solution to obtain high-resolution CPU timings by using the Windows APIs QueryPerformanceCounter and QueryPerformanceFrequency`. When your hardware is not very uncommon there is no reason to believe that `QueryPerformanceCounter` is the wrong choice here. And the problems were described with RDTSC.

Comment: [Boost::date_time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html) provides a high resolution clock :`ptime microsec_clock::local_time()` but it does not work on win32 implementation and perhaps this API is not well suited for your performance requirements.

Comment: @MatsPetersson (first comment) One thing I did not mention - the rendering thread performs interpolation based on calculated velocities of scene objects, this is to allow for a configuration with slower update rates, so a higher-than-update-rate rendering rate is not a waste of frames.

Comment: @MatsPetersson (second comment) I am prepared to work around problems with the timing (like occasional non-monotonicity) if the majority of calls are accurate enough.

Comment: @didierc Refresh rates could be higher in the future, hence the "potential". Many displays today have refresh rates at 240Hz, over half 400Hz.

Comment: @Amo But the problem in the quote I have posted refers to `QueryPerformanceCounter`, not RDTSC. I need timing on two threads. Hence the doubt on my part of it being the right choice in this situation.

Comment: @Laurent My project is cross-platform and I have found appropriate high resolution timing APIs on Unix-like systems. It is porting to Windows that is the problem.

Comment: [KB274323](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/274323) explains in great detail what this problem is about. But the link you posted does not. It says you shoud prefer QPC over RDTSC. However, the hardware described in `KB274323` is mostly outdated and thus the entire problem is sort of "history". But there is also some sample code which helps to deal with the problem.